# Tokudb HotBackup

Tags: backup, percona-server, tokudb

I was trying to evaluate the latest tokudb Hotbackup for percona's tokudb engine.

This install is under debian (Ubuntu 14)

I was able to get all the packages installed with out error and get all the base toku plugins installed.

Attempting to install the backup plug i get

```
mysql> install plugin tokudb_backup soname 'tokudb_backup.so';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so: undefined symbol: tokubackup_version_string)

mysql> select @@version;
+-------------+
| @@version   |
+-------------+
| 5.6.27-75.0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@tokudb_version;
+------------------+
| @@tokudb_version |
+------------------+
| 5.6.27-75.0      |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Edits to comments: *

This file does exist in the filesystem

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23736 Nov  3 05:30 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so
```

How can I get this installed?

Comment: You have, presumbably, checked that the file specified is located at the position specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Percona TokuBackup:

Run `ps_tokudb_admin --enable-backup` to add the preload-hotbackup option into [mysqld_safe] section of my.cnf.

```
$ sudo ps_tokudb_admin --enable-backup
Checking SELinux status...
INFO: SELinux is disabled.

Checking if preload-hotbackup option is already set in config file...
INFO: Option preload-hotbackup is not set in the config file.

Checking TokuBackup plugin status...
INFO: TokuBackup plugin is not installed.

Adding preload-hotbackup option into /etc/my.cnf
INFO: Successfully added preload-hotbackup option into /etc/my.cnf
PLEASE RESTART MYSQL SERVICE AND RUN THIS SCRIPT AGAIN TO FINISH INSTALLATION!
```

Restart mysql service

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Run `ps_tokudb_admin --enable-backup` again to finish installation of TokuBackup plugin

```
$ sudo ps_tokudb_admin --enable-backup
Checking SELinux status...
INFO: SELinux is disabled.

Checking if preload-hotbackup option is already set in config file...
INFO: Option preload-hotbackup is set in the config file.

Checking TokuBackup plugin status...
INFO: TokuBackup plugin is not installed.

Checking if Percona Server is running with libHotBackup.so preloaded...
INFO: Percona Server is running with libHotBackup.so preloaded.

Installing TokuBackup plugin...
INFO: Successfully installed TokuBackup plugin.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is permission problem. 
Your error:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library
```

Your plugin file permission:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23736 Nov  3 05:30 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/tokudb_backup.so
```

user mysql - have not rights for execute plugin

compare with other plugins(default rights after installation):

```
[tech@XXX ~]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin
total 2512
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27932 Jul 15 00:47 adt_null.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  38471 Jul 15 00:47 auth.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  25887 Jul 15 00:47 auth_socket.so
```

Comment: No, this is not an executable permission thing, it is world readable.  All others in the plugin directory have the same 644 permissions.   You get a very different error specifying a complete plugin that doesn't exist.  In fact you can tell it's starting to do something w/ it b/c it's giving you a symbol name extracted that it can't resolve